# Dynamic redirects with declarativeNetRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to use declarativeNetRequest to redirect all URLs from a domain to a URL with the initiator URL as an encoded parameter e.g.

```
http://www.google.com --> http://www.newsite.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
http://www.google.com?param1=true --> http://www.newsite.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fparam1%3Dtrue
```

Something like...

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "url": `http://www.newsite.com?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`
      }
    }
  }
```

Is this possible to do? If not is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using regexFilter like `".+"` and then redirect to `"http://www.newsite.com?url=\\0"`. It probably won't encode the URL but it may still work. If not, try matching just the part after `https://`

Comment: That works great bar the encoding @wOxxOm

Comment: Could you give the full code for this answer?

Comment: Hey @tob88! Could you please give the full code for this solution? Thanks!

Comment: Have posted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "regexSubstitution": "http://www.newsite.com?url=\\0"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^https://www.google.com(.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

It won't URL encode it but I've found it's not really an issue provided the parameter is at the end. Also be careful to limit it to particular sites in the regex or else you could end up with an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, tob88! I've been stuck on this issue for two days and was just about to give up!

Comment: is it possible to navigate it to "extensionPath based page" in place of "http://www.newsite.com" along with parameter as source url?